# How to hide the name of the Windows 8.1 desktop tile?

Tags: windows, start-menu, windows-8.1, live-tiles

After customizing my Windows 8.1 start screen with Oblytile, the Desktop tile is the last one remaining with a name. I'd like to change that. Sure I could just create a new tile with Oblytile, but I'd loose the special "look" of this tile. Are there any possibilities to get rid of the tile name?

I thought about changing of a registry entry, but I'm a little lost

Comment: Are you asking for a way to do this without third-party software?

Comment: I wouldn't mind if there is a slim third party software like Oblytile, which can remove the name but keep the rest of the look (large size, preview of desktop backround). I thought there must me a registry entry somewhere, where I change a value and that's it. But maybe I'm wrong on that.

Comment: You can replicate the large icon but the desktop preview is going to be unique to that tile.